# Typed.js restrict first element from backspace

Tags: jquery, typed

I have following code for Typed.js (https://github.com/mattboldt/typed.js/)

js

```
  $(function(){
     $("h2").typed({
        strings: ["This should stay forever. ", "Loop Element 1", "Loop Element 2", "Loop Element 3"],
        typeSpeed: 0,
        loop: true
    });
});
```

html

```
<h2></h2>
```

css

```
body{background: #000; color: lime; }
.typed-cursor{opacity: 0;  display:none; }
```

It's running in a loop at the moment. Here is my code [CodePen.io](http://codepen.io/sajidshah/pen/YPZBKM)

I want it to run it in loop but I want the first element to appear  as it is appearing at the moment. Once it appears I want it to stay and then rest of the elements will be typing in and out and they will be in the loop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

update:

Just figured out answer. Here is what I am doing

js

```
 $(function(){
    $("h2 .first").typed({
        strings: ["This should stay forever. "],
        typeSpeed: 0,
        callback: function() {
          showThis();
        },

    });

 function showThis(){

    $("span.second").typed({
          strings: ["Loop Element 1", "Element 2 Here", "New Element 3", "Element # 4"],
          backDelay: 1500,    
          typeSpeed: 100,
          backSpeed: 100,
          loop: true,

      });

  }
});
```

css

```
body{background: #000; color: lime; }

.typed-cursor{
    display:none;
}
```

HTML

```
<h2><span class="first"></span><span class="second"></span></h2>
```

Here is the pencode: [PenCode](http://codepen.io/sajidshah/pen/YPZBKM)